# AVR Timer interrupts

Tags: assembly, timer, avr

I don't understand hwo to work with interrupts and timer. Can you explain how to?
I read man's but didn't understand nothing. This is the code:

```
    .include "C:\Users\user\Downloads/m328Pdef.inc"  
.MACRO  INVBM
    .if @0 < 0x40
    PUSH    R16
    PUSH    R17
    IN      R16,@0
    LDI     R17,1<<@1
    EOR     R17,R16
    OUT     @0,R17
    POP     R17
    POP     R16
    .else
    PUSH    R16
    PUSH    R17
    LDS     R16,@0
    LDI     R17,1<<@1
    EOR     R17,R16
    STS     @0,R17
    POP     R17
    POP     R16
    .endif
    .ENDM
      .ORG 0
     ON_RESET:
      ldi R16, 0b1000_0001
      OUT       DDRB,       R16
      LDI       R16,        0b0100_0010 ; CTC mode Timer1
      STS       TCCR1A,     R16 ;SET FLAG ON COMPARE MATCH
      LDI       R16,        0x0D ; maybe change to 0x05 0b0000_0101 
      STS       TCCR1B,     R16 ;SET PRESCALER TO /1024
      LDI       R16,        0 ; value to compare 0*16+255
      STS       OCR1AH, R16
      LDI       R16,        255
      STS       OCR1AL,     R16
      
      MAIN_LOOP:
      INVBM     PINB,       0
      RCALL     PAUSE
      RJMP  MAIN_LOOP
      
      PAUSE:
      
      PLUPE:
      IN        R16,        TIFR0
      CPI       R16,        0b0000_0010
      BRNE      PLUPE
      LDI       R16,        0b0000_0010
      OUT       TIFR0,      R16
      RET
```

My led didn't blink.
[Connection][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EUSG.png

Comment: It would be easier to write your code in C instead of assembly, and it would make it easier for everyone to help you.

Comment: @DavidGrayson i want but my task is to do in with asm

Comment: Once you know how to do it in C, feed your C code into a compiler like avr-gcc to see how to convert it to assembly and learn from that.

Comment: Read the Atmel application notes.  They have examples in C and ASM.  This is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ;====================================================================
; Main.asm file generated by New Project wizard
;
; Created:   Ср апр 7 2021
; Processor: ATmega328P
; Compiler:  AVRASM (Proteus)
;====================================================================
.include "C:\Users\user\Downloads\m328Pdef.inc"
;====================================================================
; DEFINITIONS
.list
.def temp=r16
.MACRO  INVBM
    .if @0 < 0x40
    PUSH    R16
    PUSH    R17
    IN      R16,@0
    LDI     R17,1<<@1
    EOR     R17,R16
    OUT     @0,R17
    POP     R17
    POP     R16
    .else
    PUSH    R16
    PUSH    R17
    LDS     R16,@0
    LDI     R17,1<<@1
    EOR     R17,R16
    STS     @0,R17
    POP     R17
    POP     R16
    .endif
    .ENDM
    
    .MACRO PUSHF
    PUSH    R16
    IN  R16,SREG
    PUSH    R16
    .ENDM


    .MACRO POPF
    POP R16
    OUT SREG,R16
    POP R16
    .ENDM
    
    
    .MACRO  SETB
        .if @0 < 0x20       ; Low IO
        SBI     @0,@1
        .else
            .if @0<0x40     ; High IO
        IN      @2,@0
        ORI     @2,1<<@1
        OUT     @0,@2
            .else           ; Memory
        LDS     @2,@0
        ORI     @2,1<<@1
        STS     @0,@2
            .endif
        .endif
    .ENDM
    
.dseg
.cseg
.ORG $000        ; (RESET) 
         RJMP   RESET
         .ORG $002
         RETI             ; (INT0) External Interrupt Request 0
         .ORG $004
         RETI             ; (INT1) External Interrupt Request 1
         .ORG $006
         RETI             ; (TIMER2 COMP) Timer/Counter2 Compare Match
         .ORG $008
         RETI             ; (TIMER2 OVF) Timer/Counter2 Overflow
         .ORG $00A
         RETI             ; (TIMER1 CAPT) Timer/Counter1 Capture Event
         .ORG $00C 
         RETI             ; (TIMER1 COMPA) Timer/Counter1 Compare Match A
         .ORG $00E
         RETI             ; (TIMER1 COMPB) Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
         .ORG $010
         RETI             ; (TIMER1 OVF) Timer/Counter1 Overflow
         .ORG $012
         RETI ; (TIMER0 OVF) Timer/Counter0 Overflow
         .ORG $014
         RETI           ; Timer1 Capture
         .ORG $016
         RJMP   Timer1_IRQ           ; Timer1 compare A
         .ORG $018
         RETI            ;Compare B
         .ORG $01A
         RETI           ; Timer1 overflow
         .ORG $01C
         RETI             ; (ADC) ADC Conversion Complete
         .ORG $01E
         RETI             ; (EE_RDY) EEPROM Ready
         .ORG $020
         RETI            ; (ANA_COMP) Analog Comparator
         .ORG $022
         RETI             ; (TWI) 2-wire Serial Interface
         .ORG $024
         RETI             ; (INT2) External Interrupt Request 2
         .ORG $026
         RETI             ; (TIMER0 COMP) Timer/Counter0 Compare Match
         .ORG $028
         RETI             ; (SPM_RDY) Store Program Memory Ready
        .ORG $02A
         RETI 
         .ORG $02C
         RETI 
         .ORG $02E
         RETI 
         .ORG $030
         RETI 
         
         .ORG $032
         RETI 
         
         
        .ORG   INT_VECTORS_SIZE
        
    Timer1_IRQ:
        CLI
        INVBM   PORTB, 0
        
        SEI
        RETI

    
      

;====================================================================
; CODE SEGMENT
;====================================================================
Reset:      LDI     R16,Low(RAMEND) ; Инициализация стека
            OUT     SPL,R16         ; Обязательно!!!

            LDI     R16,High(RAMEND)
            OUT     SPH,R16




Start:
ldi temp, 0b1111_1111 ; Устанавливает биты в 1 на выход
out DDRB, temp; OUTPUT PORTB0 
clr temp

LDI temp,0x0C
STS TCCR1B, temp
LDI temp,0x00
STS TCCR1A, temp
;LDI    temp,   0b1000_0000
;OUT    SREG,   temp
;SETB   TIMSK1,TOIE1,R16
SETB    TIMSK1,OCIE1A,R16
;LDI    temp,   0b0000_0001 ; TOIE in TISK1 OVERFLOW INTERRUPT ENABLE TIMER1 INT ENABLE
;STS    TIMSK1, temp
LDI     temp,   0x1E
STS     OCR1AH, temp
LDI     temp,   0x84
STS     OCR1AL, temp
SEI


Loop:
;ldi temp, 1 ;Загрузить константу в регистр 
;out PortB, temp
;clr temp
;out PortB, temp
;LDI temp,0x0F
;STS OCR1AH, temp
;LDI temp,0xFF
;STS OCR1AL, temp
      rjmp  Loop
```

MAIN Steps to make it works:
1)Make handlers to all we need interrupt registers. To other write RETI.

2)Stack register interrupt must be initialised. (RJMP RESET)

3)Write handler Timer.

4)Make used bits to the used ports with DDR(A/B/C/D). 1 - output, 0 - input.

5)Configure Timers TCCR1B (for 1 timer) 0000_0101 - 1024 prescaler Works once becaule times becomes overflow. Table can be found in net. 0000_1101 - Same but after 1st interrupt next will be start automatically by clear overflow timer.

6)TCCR1A 0000_0000 if u don't want to use special pin to see timer condition.

7)if u use interrupt with compare A (B) u should enable it interrupts in register TIMSK1 (for 1 timer). Its table can be found in net. F.e. OCIE1A makes compare A interrupt enable.

8)Write A constant to the OCR1A (for 1 timer) register.

9)Start global interrupt

10)Make Loop sycle.

It sounds horrible but maybe this can help people like me.